# Youtube data api v3 and angular 2+

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Im here to ask if it's possible to fully use youtube data api v3 with angular 2+, the documentation just have examples from javascript like authentication, playlist videos, insert a playlist and search of videos ([samples](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/))

I'm trying to upload a video, using parameter like:

```
(gapi.client as any).youtube.videos.insert({
    "resource": {
        // Video title and description
        "snippet": {
            "title": "Test",
            "description": "Test video upload via YouTube API"
        },
        "status": {
            "privacyStatus": "private"
        }
    }, 
    "part": "snippet,status,id", 
    "media": {
        "body": video
    })
```

My problem is that even like this, it always return error 404 : "The request does not include the video content.", documentation says the videos needs to be video/* or application/octet-stream, and my video object is a File extended from Blob.

What could i'm possibly doing wrong? 
If it's the video file, what I have to do to work?

PS: "(gapi.client as any).youtube" has this any, because youtube is not a property from the interface, its loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Solved
I'm brazilian then I was searching portuguese documentation, that is quite poor, when changed to English, I found 2 archives cors_upload.js and upload_video.js [JS samples](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/tree/master/javascript) in the documentation, converted then to typescript  and now it works.

Comment: i want same integration Youtube Data API v3 to use in my angular 2 project, please can you help me to know how to start.I read document from google.youtube.com, but i have not idea where to i start , and i create Client ID and Client Secret.

Comment: @BrijeshMavani I use [this npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-gapi) but it's for angular 4+, use this and the documentation for youtube data api v3 in javascript to make your own api. But remember youtube gapi client can´t upload videos (i think) then you will need the link in my previous answer.

Comment: Yes thanks, but I solved it, and I'm an Indian, I made it through the documentation for youtube data API v3.